# How to limit WP_Query results to last X number of posts published?

Tags: php, wordpress

My aim is to limit the results of my query to the last X number of posts published.

So far, my query looks like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Is there a parameter I can use or should I write a custom SQL query?

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the parameters WP_Query takes is `posts_per_page`. It sorts by most recent post by default so you should only need the posts_per_page parameter.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '5'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: But wouldn't this query still return _all_ posts?

Comment: No, it will limit the query. The direct query from the above code is as follows:
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5`

Comment: @Ryan I tested this /page/2/ 3,4,5,6,99999 exist and work. This doesn't limit anything. Only number of posts per page.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Solution :

   $args = array('post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => 'your no of post', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'DESC');
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

   AND FOR Custom Query
   global $wpdb;

   $qyery="your custom query here";
   $wpdb->query($query); Use this function 

   or 

   $wpdb->get_results( $query, output_type );
```